# CEM3 or FR4 pcb, which is the lightest material?

Tags: pcb, pcb-layers

There is nothing about weight in the substrate datasheets I found.

Between CEM-3 or FR4, which is the lightest material ?
What is the average weight by surface for CEM-3 boards ?

Comment: Well, that's a darn good question. I had never noticed that PCB dielectric datasheets didn't specify a material density...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

CEM-3 is lighter than FR4,the average weight is about 3.5KG/sqm. but now most of PCB manufacturers less use CEM-3 material to make PCB,almost use FR4 material.

Comment: It would be clearer to quote the density of FR4 too (and clean up the grammar and formatting).